# How do I rename a mongodb replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I started up a few MongoDB replica sets with the default configuration and added them to [Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/), but since the default replica set name is "rs0", they're hard to tell apart in the UI. Is there a way to change the name of a replica set, preferably without having to drop and re-import all of the data in the cluster?

I've tried using `rs.reconfig` ([link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/)) but it doesn't allow you to change the replica set name.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes! The process is pretty simple:

1. Start all of the nodes in the non-replicated mode

   - Stop `mongod` on each server
   - Start `mongod` back up. If you use `/etc/mongod.conf`, remove the `replication` section. If you don't, omit the `--replSet` option to `mongod`
2. Flush the `local` database where the replication set configuration is cached

   - On each server, open a mongo shell as the admin user and run `use local; db.dropDatabase()` (Make sure that admin user / root user has `dbAdmin` role on `local` db)
3. Start all of the nodes again in replicated mode

   - Stop `mongod` on each server
   - If you use `/etc/mongod.conf`, add the `replication` section back in with the **new** name and start `mongod`. If not, start `mongod` with `--replSet <new-name>`
4. Initialize the replica set

   - Open a mongo shell as the admin user on one of the nodes. (It will become the new primary)
   - Run [`rs.initiate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/#rs.initiate). **DO NOT** pass any arguments to `rs.initiate()`. (It'll fail with an error) Any other config you want to set can be changed using [`rs.reconfig()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.reconfig/) later.
   - On the same node where your ran `rs.initiate()`, for each secondary, run [`rs.add('[secondary.host.name]')`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.add/) to add it to the replica set.
   - Wait for the secondaries to come in sync

This doesn't require you to dump and re-import your data, and it can be done with minimal downtime (and a period of degraded performance as the secondaries sync) if you automate it.

[Here's an ansible playbook](https://gist.github.com/maxrothman/4a50992ca89c922e7f68) that does the whole thing (assuming you're using `/etc/mongod.conf` and managing `mongod` via System V/Upstart/things that speak `service`.)

Comment: does this work if the replicaset is part of a sharded cluster configuration? (ie. configdb and mongos ?) thanks!

Comment: @sc2bigjoe I haven't tested it, so I can't say for sure. If you find out, please update the answer!

Comment: For those that have an issue with **RocketChat** database regarding to suddenly cache crashing for capped collection issues on OpLog. 
Dropping the local database where the replication set configuration was cached worked for me. Just follow the steps in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the existing replica set by following below steps and then can start the mongods with new replica set

1. start all mongods without --replSet

   mongod --dbpath data/rs3 --port 27019 --oplogSize 64
   Note: - Above command is for windows machine
2. start mongo for all the respective mongods remove the existing replica set
   use local
   db.system.replset.remove({_id:'OldReplicaSetName'})
3. start each mongod with the new replica set with --replSet 
   ex - mongod --dbpath data/rs3 --port 27019 --oplogSize 64 --replSet mySet
       Note: - Above command is for windows machine